# Using active choice reactive parameter in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using the active choice reactive parameter and I would like to access the selected value in my jenkinsfile.

[image: Environment settings]

[image: Active choice reactive parameter]

[image: Referencing environment settings]

Is there any way I can access select_server in my jenkinsfile? because I tried `${select_server}` and this did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending some time on this, I found a way of accessing it in jenkinsfile. the reactive choice parameter could simply be accessed by doing

```
 ${params.Select_Server}
```

In my example the name of the paramter is `"Select_Server"`. Maybe this could help someone in  the future

Comment: Hello, using ``` echo ${params.var_name}``` didn't access the variable, it still prints the same syntax instead of value. I am using both the String parameter and Active choice parameter.